# Azure VM metadata missing / emtpy publicIpAddress

Tags: azure, metadata, azure-vm

On an Azure VM when querying for metadata, the publicIpAddress has no value even though the machine as a public IP.

```
curl -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2019-11-01"
```

returns an empty string for publicIpAddress

```
{
  "compute": {
    // ... Omitted for brevity
  },
  "network": {
    "interface": [
      {
        "ipv4": {
          "ipAddress": [
            {
              "privateIpAddress": "10.3.0.4",
              "publicIpAddress": ""
            }
          ],
         // ... Rest has been omitted for brevity
```

Does anyone know why? I checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service, but couldn't find any reason for the public IP address not to show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your public IP address is Standard SKU instead of Basic SKU, which does not support instance metadata service.

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/public-ip-addresses#standard):

> Only Public IP addresses with basic SKU are available when using instance metadata service IMDS. Standard SKU is not supported.

This [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/44314) also has more information.

I've also tested this with both basic and standard SKU public IP addresses, and standard SKU will give you `"publicIpAddress":""` when querying the instance metadata instance API.

### Solution

To be able to use the instance metadata service, you need to use a **Basic SKU** public IP address. You *cannot* change the SKU once a public IP address is created, as highlighted in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-public-ip-address#create-a-public-ip-address).

Instead, you could first disassociate your **Standard SKU** public IP address instance from your virtual machine network interface, create a new public IP address with **Basic SKU**, then associate this public IP address with your virtual machine network interface. This is required since a network interface can only have one public IP address associated to it.

### Checking Public IP Address SKU

You can run [`Get-AzPublicIpAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-azpublicipaddress?view=azps-4.3.0) from Azure PowerShell command to check your public address SKU:

```bsh
(Get-AzPublicIpAddress -Name "PUBLIC-IP-NAME" -ResourceGroupName "RESOURCE-GROUP").Sku.Name
```

Or using [`az network public-ip show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/public-ip?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-public-ip-show) from Azure CLI if you prefer:

```
az network public-ip show -n "PUBLIC-IP-NAME" -g "RESOURCE-GROUP" --query "sku.name"
```

Or just check via Azure portal by navigating to your public IP address instance.

Answer (score 2):

My answer might be too late, but this will help others who are looking for this solution. Yes as RoadRunner mentioned you cannot access a Standard SKU public IP from the above API.

The solution is the query the **load balancer** api endpoint which will return the list of Standard public IP addresses of the VM.

API call:

```
curl -H "Metadata:true" http://169.254.169.254/metadata/loadbalancer?api-version=2020-10-01
```

> You can also use a more recent api version.

Response:

```json
{
  "loadbalancer": {
    "publicIpAddresses": [
      {
        "frontendIpAddress": "20.X.Y.Z",
        "privateIpAddress": "10.X.Y.Z"
      }
    ],
    "inboundRules": [],
    "outboundRules": []
  }
}
```

The **publicIpAddresses** will contain all the standard IP's associated with the VM.

The key **frontendIpAddress** is the public IP address of the VM.